# How to create a two column footnote in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I want to create two column footnote in word 2007 but it creates just one column footnotes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

Word is not capable of doing that for you. It is designed to create footnotes in the same number of columns as the document.

The alternative is to create footnotes manually in a table at the bottom of the table.

Here's a [link](http://word.tips.net/T000322_Footnotes_in_Two_Columns.html) to an article explaining and providing some additional source for creating that custom table.